# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default' in json/__init__.py in dumps

Tags: python, django, json, tastypie

I have a django server running, and, out of nowhere, I got this error. I really have no idea what changes led to this.

I'm trying to solve this for hours, but I can't find why this is happening.

Please give me a few ideas.

Ask me if you want a specific part of my code. Although the Python Path is not mentioning any of my files..

[image: Bug python]

**Full traceback :**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://whimbee-django.alwaysdata.net/api/v2/eventchat/?format=json

Django Version: 1.4.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'tastypie',
 'core',
 'iospush')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.XsSharing')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/alwaysdata/python/django/1.4.1/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/alwaysdata/python/django/1.4.1/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py" in wrapper
  264.                 return self._handle_500(request, e)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py" in _handle_500
  286.             return self.error_response(request, data, response_class=response_class)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py" in error_response
  1243.             serialized = self.serialize(request, errors, desired_format)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/resources.py" in serialize
  397.         return self._meta.serializer.serialize(data, format, options)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/serializers.py" in serialize
  187.         serialized = getattr(self, "to_%s" % desired_format)(bundle, options)
File "/home/whimbee-django/modules/django_tastypie-0.9.15-py2.6.egg/tastypie/serializers.py" in to_json
  356.             return simplejson.dumps(data, cls=json.DjangoJSONEncoder, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
File "/usr/languages/python/2.6/lib/python2.6/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  237.         **kw).encode(obj)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v2/eventchat/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'
```

Comment: Without your code and the actual traceback, the error message is pretty much useless to us.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Alright, I added the traceback. Although I really have no idea where this is coming from. So I wouldn't know what part of my code to post.

Comment: I believe there's another exception hidden below the one you're seeing. The traceback shows tastypie's error 500 handler executing and then crashing on some data. Can you trap the exception that's happening in the actual view?

Comment: @Simon I'm using django and tastypie as an API, so I never use views. So far I was debugging with emails... Messy, I know. The thing is : I erased all the changes I had made to my code. It seems like it's coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick look at the `json` code, it seems to be calling `cls()` with a keyword `default`.  By default, `cls=JSONEncoder`, but in this case, it is `json.DjangoJSONEncoder` (defined in `django_tastypie`), which seems not to comply with that implicit requirement, of taking a `default` keyword.

From the docs:

> To use a custom `JSONEncoder` subclass (e.g. one that overrides the
>   `.default()` method to serialize additional types), specify it with
>   the `cls` kwarg; otherwise `JSONEncoder` is used.

Perhaps you should try upgrading to the latest version of tastypie, and/or report a bug.

Comment: Interesting. I'm going to look into this.

Comment: I actually downgraded it from 0.9.15 to 0.9.11. It's weird because my environment is supposed to be compatible with 0.9.15 (django1.4, python2.6, dateutils1.5, mimeparse1.3).
Do you think I should report it ?